# Does a Flex scanner automatically convert tabs into spaces?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

My input consists of: `A tab B tab C`

I wrote a scanner with two rules: one rule matches on strings that don't contain a tab. The other rule matches on tabs. For the first rule, I output the string that was matched. I expected the first rule to be activated three times, outputting "A" the first time, "B" the second time, and "C" the third time. Instead, the rule is activated once and outputs: `A       B       C`. Why? It appears that Flex (or the scanner) has converted the tabs in the input to spaces. Is my diagnosis correct? How to turn off that behavior? I don't want the tabs converted to spaces.

Here's my scanner:

```
%option noyywrap
%%
[^\t]+      { fprintf(stdout,"Got %s with length %d, \n",yytext,yyleng); }
\t          { fprintf(stdout, "Found a tab\n"); }
%%
int main()
{yylex();}
```

Comment: Your editor probably converted the tabs to spaces -- use `hd` or some other program to see what you're actually giving as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, flex does not ever convert tabs to spaces -- it does not do any conversion of input characters.  So you probably have something else that has converted your tabs into spaces.  Perhaps your editor has done so on the file you're feeding to your program.

Comment: The first thing I did was to inspect my input using a hex editor. My input definitely contains the tab character: 41 09 42 09 43

Comment: @roger: And how are you feeding that input to the scanner?

Comment: From a Windows command line: more file.txt | tabtest.exe

Comment: `more` will convert tabs to spaces.  Try `tabtest.exe < file.txt`

Comment: Ha! That did it! Now it is working correctly. I didn't realize that "more" converts tabs to spaces. That is really good to know. Thank you @Chris Dodd